# Simplify if statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq, if-statement

How can I simplify such statement:

```
    var someList = new List<someType>();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(groupId))
    {
        someList = CTX.Values.Include(c => c.Customer).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        someList = CTX.Values.Include(c => c.Customer).Where(c => c.GroupId== groupId).ToList();

    }
```

The difference is only in `.Where(c => c.GroupId== groupId)`. Is it possible to include the condition `String.IsNullOrEmpty(groupId)` inside the query statement?

Comment: I deleted my reply because I don't think you should 'simplify' it. Your code is easier to understand than what has been posted yet (mine included).

Comment: as a side-note: I'd replace `var someList=new List<someType>();` with `List<someType> someList;`, since the value won't be used.

Comment: @MichaelViktorStarberg The main problem with your answer isn't that it's hard to read, but that it's wrong.

Comment: This question is more suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can construct the query in multiple steps. Simply add the `Where` part only when `groupId` is not empty.

The query will only be executed once you call `ToList()`.

```
var values = CTX.Values.Include(c => c.Customer);

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(groupId))
  values = values.Where(c => c.GroupId == groupId);

someList = values.ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, this one is the most readable and achieves the main goal!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this?

```
someList = CTX.Values.Include(c => c.Customer)
       .Where(c => String.IsNullOrEmpty(groupId)
                   || c.GroupId== groupId)
       .ToList();
```

**EDITED BY PLB REQUEST :)**

```
bool isGroupValid = String.IsNullOrEmpty(groupId);
someList = CTX.Values.Include(c => c.Customer)
       .Where(c => isGroupValid
               || c.GroupId== groupId)
       .ToList();
```

Comment: _Note:_ `groupId` will be checked if it's `null` or `empty string` on every iteration (I know that if this is a bottleneck there are greater problems ;) ).

Comment: @PLB  It is just idea. It is easy to refactor to avoid that bottleneck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
.Where(c => String.IsNullOrEmpty(groupId))
```

That is:

```
CTX.Values.Include(c => c.Customer)
    .Where(c => c.GroupId == groupId || c => String.IsNullOrEmpty(groupId))
    .ToList();
```